# Using the filter transform in Debezium 1.5

Tags: debezium

I want to filter some records in a source connector that I created.
The image contains the `debezium-scripting-1.5.0.Beta1.jar` in `/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql` (Enabled using the property `"ENABLE_DEBEZIUM_SCRIPTING=true"` on the connect-base image).

My connector has the following properties :

```
"transforms": "filter",
"transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter"
```

When registering my source connector, it fails to configure the connector with the following stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.config.EnumeratedValue
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

The message is clear : I am not finding the `EnumeratedValue` class (which is part of the debezium core package).
But when I change the `"transforms"` property to `"unwrap"`, there is no more error.

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this? Having the same issue

Comment: @krakig can you post your solution here?

Answer (score 2):

**This method worked on me.**
I have `<some-path>/debezium/debezium-connector-mongo/` folder, and 
`plugin.path=<some-path>/debezium` 
When I start connector, it works fine.
However, when I add debezium-script plugin, which in `<some-path>/debezium/debezium-script/` folder (in same `plugin.path`), the error appear.

So I moved any plugins in `<some-path>/debezium/debezium-script/` into `<some-path>/debezium/debezium-connector-mongo/` (merge two folder into one), this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @0123hoang answer, you should add `debezium-scripting-*.*.*.Final.jar` file alongside `debezium-core-*.*.*.Final.jar` which is located in the debezium folder under the kafka connect plugins directory.

In my case I also had to add groovy files so after extracting `apache-groovy-binary-*.*.*.zip` I found the files `groovy-*.*.*.jar` and `groovy-jsr223-*.*.*.jar` under `lib` directory and put them alongside `debezium-core-*.*.*.Final.jar` and my filter smt started working.

Reference: [link](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/07/06/how-use-debezium-smt-groovy-filter-routing-events#creating_the_image)